# Why does the npm YAML library have a max alias number?

Tags: javascript, npm, yaml

I am using the npm package `yaml` do store densely inter-referential Javascript objects to a text format that I can later restore in Javascript, and also to do deep copying in-memory (by serializing and then unserializing a deeply nested object.)

I've recently run into an error message regarding a max object size:

```
Excessive alias count indicates a resource exhaustion attack
```

Is there a legitimate danger in serializing inter-referential objects if all YAML does is make an alias reference? (There's no danger of cycles in traversing the graph, right?) – Is there any way of disabling this max, or an alternative for storing inter-referential objects to text / deep-copying them?

Thanks!

---

Edit: I accepted `flyx`'s answer to the question because it better explained the context of why there is a max alias count, but `rexfordkelly` better explains how to disable the check in the npm `yaml` library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some YAML implementations are prone to the [billion laughs attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion_laughs_attack). The example given there is

```yaml
a: &a ["lol","lol","lol","lol","lol","lol","lol","lol","lol"]
b: &b [*a,*a,*a,*a,*a,*a,*a,*a,*a]
c: &c [*b,*b,*b,*b,*b,*b,*b,*b,*b]
d: &d [*c,*c,*c,*c,*c,*c,*c,*c,*c]
e: &e [*d,*d,*d,*d,*d,*d,*d,*d,*d]
f: &f [*e,*e,*e,*e,*e,*e,*e,*e,*e]
g: &g [*f,*f,*f,*f,*f,*f,*f,*f,*f]
h: &h [*g,*g,*g,*g,*g,*g,*g,*g,*g]
i: &i [*h,*h,*h,*h,*h,*h,*h,*h,*h]
```

You can test this in the [online demo of js-yaml](https://nodeca.github.io/js-yaml/) which cannot process it (I don't know much about the JS ecosystem – the YAML implementation you use seems to be a different or modified one (?) and I can't find an online demo of it). Theoretically, this should not be a problem since YAML defines anchors & aliases to generate references, not copies. However, for whatever reason, some implementations copy the lists instead (PyYAML is also guilty of this, and quite some implementations are rewrites of PyYAML in different languages).

Answer (score 2):

You can  turn off this check by setting maxAliasCount=-1 in yaml parse options.

YAML, is attempting to protect against essentially a form of denial of service attach. If you YAML contains no user controlled content, and is sound, it should be fine to disable these checks.

But, yeah, there would be a danger of running out of resources, while processing the YAML.

I would test and profile it.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is a better answer to my practical question, but on consideration the question I put in the title asks more for the context, so I accepted flyx, but I appreciate your time and you definitely helped me get unstuck! Thanks so much.